# Cocoa - Schedule timed tasks to fetch data

Tags: ios, macos, swift, cocoa

recently I am writing an OS X menu bar app that display the current weather info.

I am requesting the data using an external weather API, and suppose I can call a `getData()` method in my `AppDelegate` to make a HTTP request and get the data back.

Currently I am using `NSTimer` but to make the request every 15min in the `AppDelegate.swift`

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(interval, target: self, selector: "getData:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

However, now what I want to achieve is to execute this method at a specific time. For example, on an hourly basis everyday - get data on 10:00, 11:00, 12:00, etc...

Can anyone suggest on how to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: set this property @property (copy) NSDate *fireDate;

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do this:

```
var fireDate = NSDate()
var timer = NSTimer(fireDate: fireDate, interval: 60.0, target: self, selector: "getData:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
timer.fire()
```